# dplyr `slice_max` interpolation not working

Tags: r, dplyr

Given a `data.frame`:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(0)
df <- tibble(A = 1:10, B = rnorm(10), C = rbinom(10,2,0.6))
var <- "B"
```

I'd like to get filter the data frame by the highest values of the variable in `var`. Logically, I'd do either:

```
df %>%
    slice_max({{ var }}, n = 5)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>       A     B     C
#>   <int> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1  1.26     1
df %>%
    slice_max(!! var, n = 5)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>       A     B     C
#>   <int> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1  1.26     1
```

But neither interpolation is working... what am I missing here?

Expected output would be the same as:

```
df %>%
    slice_max(B, n = 5)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>       A     B     C
#>   <int> <dbl> <int>
#> 1    10 2.40      0
#> 2     3 1.33      2
#> 3     4 1.27      1
#> 4     1 1.26      1
#> 5     5 0.415     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the newer `.data` version as outlined [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html):

```
df %>%
  slice_max(.data[[var]] , n = 5)

#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>       A     B     C
#>   <int> <dbl> <int>
#> 1    10 2.40      0
#> 2     3 1.33      2
#> 3     4 1.27      1
#> 4     1 1.26      1
#> 5     5 0.415     2
```

I am puzzled by why your approach is get the first row only though!

Comment: In fact, it gets the fifth row (which makes sense with n=5). Thanks for the link, very useful!

Answer (score 1):

We may convert to `sym` and evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    slice_max(!! rlang::sym(var), n = 5)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
      A     B     C
  <int> <dbl> <int>
1    10 2.40      0
2     3 1.33      2
3     4 1.27      1
4     1 1.26      1
5     5 0.415     2
```